# Plugin architecture and relationships in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, architecture

I have a C# application based on a plugin architecture. The base app includes two plugins, one for authentication and one for purchases.

The first one contains the Users table:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = new();
    
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The second one contains Purchases:

```
public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; } = new();

    public string ProductName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The two plugins are fully independent (they are two projects that do not have access to each other), but they share one database. They also do not have common models, they are separate solutions*

The problem is that the purchase plugin stores information about which user purchased something (has UserId).
Is it possible to create a relationship between these two tables in two independent projects? Or maybe I should just not make a relationships? But there's a problem. What happens if I need to delete a user? There is a risk that another plugin will still store data associated with this user.

Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Guess thats the price you pay for using that architecture. But if you delete a user, and the other plugins do stuff involving that user, well where are they getting the user details from in order to do something with it? Surely the user table is the source of truth as to which users are valid in the system. But if thats not the case, guess you can never delete them, instead you'll need a delete flag to mark the record as deleted.

Comment: I can't quite get my head around how this architecture works... surely any plugin which can store a user id, has to get the valid user id from somewhere? And that somewhere should be the database table? So every plugin would need to access the user model?

Comment: The main application (to which you connect plugins) manages all this. Plugins add tables to the database and provide various services for data processing and database operations (on tables provided by this plugin). Example: you make a purchase in the application, the main application downloads the user from the authentication plugin, and then adds information about the purchase to the shopping plugin.

Comment: Well in that case I think you have to trust the main application not to pass a deleted user details to another plugin. But if there is a chance they could be out of sync, you probably cannot delete users, instead you'd have to flag them as deleted.

Comment: Of course how you should handle purchases against a deleted user is some business logic you have to work out...

Comment: Having an FK relationship is good for database integrity, but its not essential, if you trust your app. It seems like in this case adding it would go against the design principles of architecture. You just may need some checks for hanging records.

Comment: You're missing the "first" and most important plugin; that the 2 "independent" plugins "depend" on; and that is the "user" plugin; which comes "before" any authentication or "purchasing". The "user plugin" provides the "bi-directional" relationship between authentication and purchasing. Withdrawing purchasing or authentication does make the "user" disappear.

Answer (score 0):

"The two plugins are fully independent", except they aren't...  Indeed, notice that the fact that you refer to a User entity in Purchase, even if the reference is simply by ID, does already say that the second plugin has to "know about Users".

Which, given that I find the overall requirement, as you briefly describe it (in a comment to the question), pretty reasonable, is to say that you do need to **allow plugins to depend on other plugins** (directly or indirectly, see below).

An easy but relatively clean approach would be that each plugin *solution* has at least two *projects*, one for the "data" only (data types, but whatever is needed really), to be referenced by dependent plugins. -- For a more dynamic architecture (where it's not known in advance *which* User), there is still an abstract User to be defined somewhere and to be injected not just in the app but in every plugin that needs it. (I am not getting into any details: so many variations and degrees are possible that this deserves focused questions.)